# What is the logic behind tasks in Rake versus under `rails`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I try to grasp the logic behind some tasks being "rails" whereas others, the majority, is found as rake task. Why `rails server` and not `rake server` for example?

I can understand that the bootstrapping cannot be done in rake: after all, you first need a *rakefile* and other requirements before you can start using rake. So creating the project with a `rails` binary seems only practical.

But why `generate`, `server`, `console`, yet not `migrate` or `assets`? I don't see the logic. Is there any?

Comment: I'd add that rake is more for automating tasks, like might be used by a CI system, whereas you wouldn't do most of the rails scripts except in a console.

Comment: Sounds logical to me: `rails` is used while developing. `rake` is used when it can/will be ran in the rest of the DTAP. Would that be it?

Comment: (Moved to answer.) More or less, AFAICT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the `rails` scripts are for "live" console usage, like during development.

The `rake` tasks are more "automated" tasks, for example, that might be run as part of a build or deploy cycle, like by a CI server. Some rake tasks might group rails/etc. commands together (like tests).

Answer (score 1):

A `rake` script is a utility/build tool for some common tasks when developing. For example, you need to do deployment, run test, database stuffs, truncate log files, compile assets .... You can create your own custom rake scripts.

A `rails` script is ruby file located under script directory for the purpose of the gem `rails`. This is what the gem does. Rails is a ruby web framework, so the command `rails` is for starting the `rails` apps, go to `rails` console, `generate` files. It's bundled when you install the gem.

You can think of `rails` command like `bundle` command for bundler. `bundle install`, `bundle update` ... all are related to resolving gem dependencies. `rspec` command for running tests...

Some gems has an executable script such as `rails`, `bundler`, `capistrano`, `whenever`, `rspec`. Some other gems doesn't have such as `builder`, `will_paginate`....

You can check this out for how to add executable to a gem, http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable

Comment: You explain the reasons behind the split, but not the logic. E.g. `rspec` has a counterpart in rake, it is even the default rake-task in a Rails project. I understand the logic behind having a `rails new` command as mentioned in my question. But that does not explain why `rails generate` is a rails command, whereas `rails db:migrate` a rake. I want to know, because I develop rake and rails scripts (installers etc) and want to know what to choose: rake or rails.